# wcf server rejected client credentials

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to connect to wcf server. My code works when both server and client on the same computer. However, when the client is set on a different machine it's not working.
I found a few answers that didn't help. 
The problem I'm getting is: wcf server rejected client credentials

Here is part of the server config:

```
     <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
           <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
         </security>
```

the client config:

```
 <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
```

client code:

```
  _wcfClient = new wcfServiceClient(context, new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport),
                   new EndpointAddress(@"net.tcp://" + host +
                                @":7919/wcfControl/name/"));

    _wcfClient .Open();
```

I tried to change the server security to None, but then the server couldn't run. 
The only solution did help is to insert on the client side server windows username and password. but I want to find a better solution.

Thanks ahead for the help

Comment: Are you running client and server under same windows user?

Comment: When i tried running both server and client on the same computer under the same user it worked. When i use different computers for server and client, the connection failed. (on each computer different windows user).

Comment: Can user from client computer login to your sever computer?

Comment: no. that is my problem. *\(I manage both server and client)

Comment: Than you just have to adjust permissions for server computer, so client user can login there.